# How to use different log4j2.xml files for different webservices

Tags: java, web-services, log4j2

I am switching to log4j2 and can not figure out how to use different log4j2.xml files for different webservices. I am using WebSphere 8.5.

For example:
I have 3 webservices (ws1, ws2, and ws3) with 3 different log files (wslog1, wslog2, wslog3).

I would like to have 3 different log4j2 configuration files (eiter with different names or the same name but in different directories).

In log4j1.x I could use the PropertyConfigurator to specify the path and filename to be used for configuring log4j1.x.  This is not available in log4j2. I have created the log4j.configurationFile system property but that only allows me to specify the path and file name of a single configuration file.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate log4j2.xml configurations in separate web applications (WAR files). Within the same web application you can only have one log4j2.xml configuration.

Comment: I don't want to include the log4j2.xml file in my project. I want to have separate directories on the websphere box with the log4j2.xml files and set the path to the configuration file in code.

Comment: If you have separate web applications you can specify the location of each log4j2.xml file separately with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`.